# Как программно загрузить html страницу?

Tags: c#

## Требование

Необходима готовая библиотека, которая поддерживает функции загрузки HTML документа по ссылке, а также загружает дополнительную информацию в фоновом режиме которую предоставляет эта страница в виде ajax и прочими скриптами.

## Проблема

Есть некий сайт, зайдя на который необходимо авторизоваться. Далее нужно перейти на другую страницу этого домена и после полной загрузки страницы, вытащить информацию которая загружается уже после.
В идеале, хотелось бы видеть инструмент который сможет авторизоваться на сайте, перейти по ссылке и загрузить всю информацию. Также было бы неплохо, если бы этот инструмент мог нажать на определенную кнопку, что повлечет за собой обновление нужной информации на странице.

Comment: Вы не описали проблему. В чем возникла у вас проблема при реализации на c#?

Comment: На с# есть алгоритмы загрузки отдельно. А так что б всё и сразу и вместе - используйте ActiveX обьект InternetExplorer.Application. Я предпочитаю через js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать библиотеку [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). Все перечисленные функции присутствуют в данной библиотеке.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = new WebClient();
            var html = a.DownloadString("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525721/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83");
```

А для нажатия кнопок нужно отправлять WebRequest-ы